# python pexpect does not launch my ssh tunnel

Tags: python, ssh, pexpect

i have got this script (called tunnel):

(ip server replaced with ssh_server_ip)

```
ssh -ND 5545 -p 443 -vvv user@ssh_server_ip
```

I try to run it through python pexpect.

```
import pexpect 
import time

p = pexpect.run('./tunnel')
#does not work with spawn
#p = pexpect.spawn('./tunnel') 
p.expect('password: ')
time.sleep(2)
p.sendline('pswd')
```

when I run the script, there is a connection with the server, but it does not last long (few seconds)

```
ssh        8872    root    3u  IPv4 510801      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.36:46328->ssh_server_ip:https (ESTABLISHED)
```

if the ssh tunnel is fully established, I should have the following:

```
ssh        8130    root    3u  IPv4 503864      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.36:46326->ssh_server_ip:https (ESTABLISHED)
ssh        8130    root    4u  IPv6 505215      0t0  TCP [::1]:5545 (LISTEN)
ssh        8130    root    5u  IPv4 505216      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:5545 (LISTEN)
```

shall I use the bash expect instead of python pexpect?

thanx folks!

Comment: no error in the output of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write like this:

```
p.sendline('password')
p.expect(pexpect.EOF)
```

Otherwise the Python script will exit immediately after sending the password which in turn will kill the `ssh` command.

Comment: ok now another issue comes up; it looks like the server needs to be bombed (I need to try to connect over and over again) to accept a connexion. In my python script, an error comes up if the server does not accept the connection. So I need to loop the script while there is no connexion but I do not know what condition to use in this case.

Comment: sounds like a different problem. please ask a new question.